# Check for specific naming convention

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, findstr

I have a directory where users are saving their excel files that should adhere to a specific naming convention:

```
XX-TestFile.xlsx
```

where `XX` is a variable digit and `-TestFile.xlsx` should always be the same and not change. I'd like to be able to check through a batch job if files in the directory adhere to a specific naming convention.

If filename is misspelled, i.e. `XX-TetsFiel.xlsx`, `XX` is not a digit like `02` or even `XX-testfile.xlsx` (all lowercase), then files should move to an Error directory.

I am using below to move the files to achieve this. I am testing with `11-testFiel.xlsx` and it works just fine.

```
@echo off

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b *.xlsx ^| findstr /v "[0-9][0-9]-TestFile.xlsx"') do move "%%a" "C:\Temp\Archive\Error"
```

However, `dir /b *.xlsx | findstr /v "[0-9][0-9]-TestFile.xlsx"` allows for 109 possible combinations since `XX` is a variable with two digits like `02`. However, I would now only like to check for specific file names of 20 possible digits like `02-TestFile.xlsx`, `05-TestFile.xlsx`, `10-TestFile.xlsx`, etc. This list is fixed... So for example, if file is named `99-TestFile.xlsx` I would still like to move it to an Error archive as it is an undesired file name. Can you suggest a solution for this?

Comment: I count only 100 numbers for 00..99

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the valid names into a text file (i.e. "ValidNames.txt") and use findstr with the /G option.

```
02-TestFile.xlsx
05-TestFile.xlsx
10-TestFile.xlsx
...
```

---

```
@echo off

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('
    dir /b *.xlsx ^| findstr /vxlg:"ValidNames.txt"
') do move "%%a" "C:\Temp\Archive\Error"
```

Comment: I guess it would make sense to add the `/X` option, right?

Comment: @aschipfl With `/vl` would it make a difference?

Comment: Yes, it would, a file like `002-TestFile.xlsx` would match without `/X` and therefore not be moved...